# Regex match multiple words iteratively

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this test string:

```
{.aa1 .b3c .f4}
```

I want to extract arbitrary number of words starting with literal dot `.` inside the braces. So I wrote this JavaScript regex:

```
/{((?=\.\w+?)(\.\w+?)\s*?)*}/g
```

I'm basically looking ahead `(?=\.\w+?)`, but if there's a match it isn't captured since lookahead is zero width, so then I capture `(\.\w+?)`, and then allow for possibility of spaces `\s*?`, and then I group all this, and try to iterate by repeating it with `*`. But it doesn't work - regex101.com tells me that returns:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `.f4`
2.  `.f4`
```

.. while I'd want an array of matches being (`.aa1`, `.b3c`. `.f4`). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
string.match(/\.\w+(?=[^{}]*\})/g)
```

I assumed that the parenthesis must be closed properly.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fT0kC3/1)